# how do I get rid of multi-harmonic lines in my recordings?

Tags: recording, experiment-design, fieldwork

I'm using a DC-AC converter to run my audio-interface in the field. Everytime I use the converter to make recordings i see strong multi-harmonic 'lines' in my spectrogram. In the lab (when connected to mains power) however, the lines do not appear.

I've tried various approaches including placing sound card far from the converter and even 'grounding' the converter with a metal rod connected to the box. The lines still appear. How can I ensure the interference doesn't happen?

Comment: Could you possible add an example spectrogram? I think I also deal with what you are describing but would love to compare

Comment: Don't know if i have it at hand any more. This was looong ago :|. This actually could be a separate question :)?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AC-DC and DC-AC converters are notorious for generating noise that will interfere with recordings. Best to get rid of them entirely, if possible, i.e. by running everything on DC batteries during recording sessions.
In some setups, line drivers (0 dB gain amplifiers with low output impedance) placed close to the microphones can solve many noise issues.
Last thing to try is grounding. An art bordering black magic, where the best strategy is to try various configurations spanning from grounding the entire setup to leaving everything floating and with various parts of the setup grounded and floating, respectively, all to see whether one particular configuration is better than the others. The black magic lies in the fact that what may work well one day may, for untraceable reasons, not work at all the following day.

Comment: I am able to monitor the lab activity just from the 50 Hz ground harmonics which amplitude increases from 6am to 6pm when the automatic lab lights are on :-D.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK all consumer-grade DC-AC converters produce such multi-harmonic interference. I too had this issue, and even tried out multiple converter models with no luck.

Your best shot may be to use shielded cables for your mics, though here too i don't know if it will definitely work (if memory serves right, shielding didn't help here). The final alternative that worked for me was to ditch the converter+ soundcard combination and use another model that had DC power supply.

Also, the interference may be there on the audio, but aside from the cosmetic inconvenience - how much of it is there? It's worth quantifying the dBrms of audio recorded with/without the converter to assess if it really makes a big difference after all.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes even if the device itself is good (quiet), the power source may be noisy. Ships are notorious for their power gremlins, even on 'quiet' power supplies. It is hard for a big metal ship to have a proper ground in the ocean (see dark magic comment!).  Over the years I have gone so far as to cut my cables to bypass the DC-AC converters & power directly into batteries, use optically isolated serial port connectors and 'quiet' USB hubs (sorry, the devices I used are out of date so I cannot provide any links).